# SOSL: Ignoring fields not available for entity

Tags: salesforce, soql

I have a SOSL query that searches for Accounts and returns 3 specific fields:

```
FIND {QUERY_STRING} RETURNING Account (Id,Name,Site LIMIT 10)
```

The query works fine for some organizations, but some organizations don't have the `Site` field in their Account entity. When I run this query on such orgs' SF, I get the following error:

```
No such column 'Site' on entity 'Account'.
```

Is there a way to do one of the following?

1. Get all the available fields of the entity, without specifying them.
2. Make the query ignore the missing fields and return only the available ones.

I know I can solve this using two queries, but this is something I would like to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of [dynamic SOSL](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_CSH.htm#apex_dynamic_sosl.htm) and [schema details](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_CSH.htm#pages_dynamic_vf_globals_objecttype.htm) to build a custom SOSL query that matches the schema of each org.